# Calculating the Second Moment of a Binomial Random Variable

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

The first step in calculating the variance of a Binomial Random Variable is calculating the second moment.

**[image]**

I have no idea as to how the last two steps have happened. Why is a `n(n-1)p^2` outside the first summation and a similar expression outside the second? Also, how did the expression turn out to be the last equation?

Comment: You can do this in one line. Just represent $X$ as a sum of iid Bernoulli random variables. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First term  is obtained as follows:

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{n!(j^2-j)}{(n-j)!j!}p^j(1-p)^{n-j} &= \sum_{j=2}^{n} \frac{n!(j^2-j)}{(n-j)!j!}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}\tag{1}\\&=\sum_{j=2}^{n} \frac{n!(j(j-1))}{(n-j)!j!}p^j(1-p)^{n-j} \tag{2}\\
&= \sum_{j=2}^{n} \frac{n!}{(n-j)!(j-2)!}p^j(1-p)^{n-j} \tag{3} \\
&= n(n-1)\sum_{j=2}^{n} \frac{(n-2)!}{(n-j)!(j-2)!}p^j(1-p)^{n-j} \tag{4}\\
&= n(n-1)p^2\sum_{j=2}^{n} \frac{(n-2)!}{(n-j)!(j-2)!}p^{j-2}(1-p)^{n-j} \tag{5} \\
&= n(n-1)p^2\sum_{j'=0}^{n-2} \frac{(n-2)!}{(n-2-j')!(j')!}p^{j'}(1-p)^{n-2-j'} \tag{6} \\
&= n(n-1)p^2 \tag{7} \\
\end{align}

where equation $(1)$ is due to $j^2-j=0$ if $j=0$ or $j=1$, hence we can start summing from $2$ rather than $0$.

Equation $(2)$ is just $j^2-j=j(j-1)$.

Equation $(3)$ is due to $j!=(j-2)!j(j-1)$

Equation $(4)$ is due to $n!=(n-2)!n(n-1)$.

Equation $(5)$ is just factorize $p^2$ outside.

Equation $(6)$ is a change of variable of $j'=j-2$

To obtain equation $(7)$, notice that in equation $(6)$, the term inside the sum if the pmf of binomial distribution with parameter $n-2$ and $p$.

I will leave the second term as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

The $n$ and $n-1$ are coming out of the $n!$ remember that $n!=n*(n-1)*(n-2)!$. The $p^2$ came from the $p^j$ since $p^j=p^{j-2}*p^2$. Once this terms are out both sums (separately) are equal to the probability mass function of a binomial random variable hence they sum to 1. Hence the result.

Comment: In that case, why have the numbers on the summations changed?

Comment: For the first sum when $j=0$ or $1$ the term is 0 since $j^2-j=0$, for the second sum when $j=0$ the term is 0. So you don't have to consider those.

Answer (score 2):

They distributed out constant factors from series so that a change of variables would make it the series of probabilities for a binomial expansion $(p+1-p)^{n-1}$.   They did not show their work, thinking it would be obvious.   Clearly it is not.

I'll just do one of the terms $${
\quad \sum_{j=0}^n\dfrac{n!\ j}{(n-j)!\ j!}p^j(1-p)^{n-j} 
\\ = \sum_{j=0}^n \dfrac{n(n-1)!\,j}{(n-1-j+1)!\, j\, (j-1)!} p\, p^{j-1}(1-p)^{n-1-j+1} 
\\ = np \sum_{j=0}^n\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-(j-1))!\,(j-1)!}p^{j-1}(1-p)^{n-1-(j-1)} 
\\ = np \sum_{j-1=-1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j-1}p^{j-1}(1-p)^{n-1-(j-1)}
\\ = np \sum_{j-1=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j-1}p^{j-1}(1-p)^{n-1-(j-1)}
\\ = np \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}k p^k(1-p)^{n-1-k}
\\ = np (p+(1-p))^{n-1}
\\ = np
}$$

The other term follows likewise.  Of particular note we use the conveniention that $\binom{r}{-1}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $X_i$ are iid Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$. Now,

$$
\begin{split}
E[X^2] &= E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n X_i X_j\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nE[X_i X_j] = \sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i^2] + \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1,j\ne i}^nE[X_i X_j]\\
& = np + n(n-1)p^2,
\end{split}
$$
where we have used the fact that $E[X_i^2] = E[X_i] = p$ and $E[X_i X_j] = E[X_i]E[X_j] = p^2$ for any pair of distinct indices $(i,j)$.